# how to get a string from memcach on appengine - java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

I'm using memcache on appengine.
I inserted a json string:

```
private static CacheFactory cacheFactory = CacheManager.getInstance().getCacheFactory();;
private static Cache cache = cacheFactory.createCache(Collections.emptyMap());;
String data = "{\name\": \"jim\"}";
cache.put("1234", data);
```

now I'm trying to get the string from memcache and create a json object:

```
JSONObject dataObj =   new JSONObject(cache.get("1234")); // log  => {name: "john"}
```

this works for me well, and I get the expected JSON -> `{name: "john"}`.

Now I am getting the data before I create the json;

```
Object myData = cache.get("1234");
JSONObject dataObj =   new JSONObject(myData); // log => {"bytes":[123,34,110,97,109,101,34,58,34,106,111,104,110,34,125],"empty":false}
```

and now I am receiving the data in an byte Object -> `{bytes: [12,..],empty: false}`

What's going on? Isn't there an expected behavior?

**EDIT**
I will note that when on the [memcach-console](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/using#configuring_memcache) the value is saved ok ->  `{name: "john"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Object myData = cache.get("1234");
```

try

```
String myData = (String) cache.get("1234");
```

By the way, on App Engine I am using the following code:

```
MemcacheService memcache = MemcacheServiceFactory.getMemcacheService();
memcache.put("1234", object);
String myData = (String) memcache.get("1234");
```